# Jenkins/Fastlane: Error fatal: could not read Username for '[repository url]': Device not configured

Tags: git, jenkins, github, push, fastlane

In my **Jenkins** CI-Pipeline, I use the **Fastlane** action `push_to_git_remote` to do a git push (in the step before, an automatic commit was done). However, when I trigger the Jenkins build, I get the following error:

`fatal: could not read Username for 'https://...': Device not configured`

On other stackoverflow threads, I found the solution that no commits were made. However, that's not the problem here. Also, when I execute the fastlane action locally on my build server (without Jenkins), I have to add my git repo credentials and then, everything works.

do you have any ideas?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?